# How to solve definite integral $ \int_0^\infty \log^2 x e^{-x}dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I want to solve

$$\int_0^\infty \log^2 x \; e^{-x}dx$$

Comment: ...and what have you tried so far?

Comment: i have put x=logt

Answer (score 3):

A quick and dirty way to evaluate is to consider

$$I(a) = \int_0^{\infty} dx \, x^a \, e^{-x} = \Gamma(1+a) $$

Then the integral of interest is

$$I''(0) = \left [\Gamma(1+a) \right ]_{a=0} = \Gamma(1) \psi(1)^2 + \Gamma(1) \psi'(1)$$

Thus,

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-x} \log^2{x} = \gamma^2+\frac{\pi^2}{6} $$

Comment: Quick, for sure ! Dirty, I don't agree. Elegant, yes !! Thanks for such a beauty.